# How to fill minutes time series data with 0 in python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, sorting

I've a dataset "nodup" as follows (not sorted by time).
it's a subset from raw data, not sorted. I need to get a record by every 15 minutes, for example 08:15, 08:30, 08:45... but it only keeps records when occupancy = 1.

What I need to do is to get occupancy=0, and auto fills the related newly generated co2 and humidity by the mean of previous and next values (from same device).
:

```
 device     occupancy                time         co2   humidity 
   1          1              2019-06-27 10:17:22    818     40
   2          1              2019-06-27 10:17:22    818     39
   3          1              2019-06-27 08:00:05    625     40
   4          1              2019-06-27 12:16:53    723     40
  ....
   1          1              2019-06-28 10:17:22    818     40
   2          1              2019-06-28 10:17:22    818     39
   3          1              2019-06-28 08:02:05    625     40
   4          1              2019-06-28 12:16:53    723     40
  ....
```

What I want is as example (generate 15minutes records based on previous data , sorting by time):

```
 device     occupancy                time         co2   humidity 
   1          1              2019-06-27 08:15     818     40
   2          0              2019-06-27 08:15     XXX     XX
   3          0              2019-06-27 08:15     XXX     XX
   4          1              2019-06-27 08:15     723     40
  ....
   1          1              2019-06-27 08:30     830     45
   2          0              2019-06-27 08:30     XXX     XX
```

I've tried

```
time_first =nodup['time'].min()  
time_last = nodup['time'].max() 

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([pd.date_range(time_first, time_last,freq='15min'), 
nodup['device'].unique()], names=['time', 'device'])

result = nodup.set_index(['time','device']).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

But it runs to :

```
ValueError: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Anyone can help on this? As i review the rawdata, there are no duplicates in the line

Comment: why does 10:17 become 8:15 ? why does 12:16 become 8:15? why does 8:02 become 8:15?

Comment: @JoranBeasley thx for reply. Didn't pay much attention when paste the data here.  I've modified my question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are asking, but im going to answer based on the title

(I dont understand why 10:17 would become 8:15 for example)

```
nodup = pandas.DataFrame({
   'time': pandas.date_range('2019-01-03 22:12:13','2019-05-08 11:11:27',periods=1000)
})
```

to make all the times have ":00" for minutes

```
new_times = nodup['time'].dt.floor("1h")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the device as a index because it's not a unique index!

Indexes has to be a unique number that can't be repeated in the column.